# Using AWS Lambda function to create a monitoring website for IoT devices

Tags: aws-iot, aws

I want to create a web site to monitor my IoT devices, so I went through many tutorials to achieve that.

The most common way that is used in the tutorials is writing to DynamoDB from IoT then using Lambda to invoke the data from DynamoDB to Lambda and finally hosted by S3. But S3 hosted the static web while I need a dynamic web site in order to trigger the data from AWS IoT.

Can you please help me with this or show me a tutorial makes same thing?

Comment: What kind of devices? What kind of events/data do you want to monitor? What kind of website do you host?

Comment: What tutorial? url? And is it IoT, It looks more as a web server/page question!?

Comment: My devices are LDR sensor, robotic arm, CNC machine, i want to moniter them payload messages , i just want to keep watching the payload messages on the webpage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lambda is for running tiny functions, not long-running processes.

You should have your web page connect directly to AWS IoT using WebSockets.  Then it can get messages directly when they happen and display them, etc.

If you don't need to store your state, you don't need Dynamo or S3. (Although you may want to use S3 to host the JavaScript/HTML for your application.)